Microsoft Bot Framework : Most events do not run for Telegram Bot
I’m working with a Telegram bot using Bot Framework (.Net) and want to capture events when a user blocks the bot or starts a new conversation. With Web Chat, everything works fine, but Telegram doesn’t seem to trigger these events.
Microsoft.Bot.Builder 4.22.2

OnMembersAddedAsync
OnMembersRemovedAsync
OnCommandActivityAsync
OnMessageUpdateActivityAsync
OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync
OnEventActivityAsync
OnEndOfConversationActivityAsync
OnInstallationUpdateRemoveAsync
OnUnrecognizedActivityTypeAsync
OnInstallationUpdateAddAsync
OnEventAsync
OnTokenResponseEventAsync

Is this the expected behavior, or does the Bot Framework not support these events for Telegram bots? I couldn’t find any official information about this limitation.

Please share more details about the issue.
